# hyperref, bookmarks, and addchapter

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

When using `\addchap{}` in `scrbook` class sections below that chapter do not get the correct bookmark jump mark beyond the first use. In practice that means once you click on a bookmark that points you to a section in a chapter >1 you always end up in chapter 1. I've included an example: Once you click on the bookmark "Failing bookmark Second Introduction" it takes you to the section "First Introduction" instead of the corresponding one. `scrhack`doesnt seem to help, how do I fix this?

[image: The Failing bookmark is highlighted in this picture]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksdepth=1]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{A part}
\addchap{First Chapter}
\section{First Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First Explanation}
\lipsum[4-5]

\part{Second part}
\addchap{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[6-7]
\section{Failing bookmark Second Introduction}
\lipsum[9-10]
\section{Failing bookmark Second Explanation}
\lipsum

\part{Working Bookmark Part}
\chapter{Working Bookmark Chapter}
\lipsum[6-7]
\section{Working Bookmark Introduction}
\lipsum[9-10]
\section{Working Bookmark Explanation}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: You also get wrong section numbering. You have sections "0.1" below the \addchap. How do you want to handle this?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - that is true - I'm removing that 0 by using `\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}`-but it didn't seem relevant to the question for me, hence I had left it out.

Comment: @nhck: Why are you stripping the chapter number from the section number? This is confusing your readers (Having a reference for section 2 from first chapter and a section 2 from 4th chapter, for example -- which one do you mean then?) and asking for trouble. Now the hyper anchors must fail and the link goes wrong. If you don't need chapters at all, then use `scrartcle` or `article` instead

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You are correct. I am implementing conference proceedings, so each paper is a chapter. The reason to go w/o numbers is more aesthetical/political and not reversable. In printed form it isn't too confusing. As for the pdf: it would be more usable if you could click the sections, but if it is not possible to set the right anchor I'll just skip them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that `\theHsection` -- the id hyperref uses for the links -- is defined in a way that it is unique for every section. In your example it works by adding \thepart to `\theHsection`. If in your real document there are more unumbered chapters then you will have to add some additional counter that you increase at every \addchapter.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksdepth=1]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\theHsection{\thepart-\HyperLocalCurrentHref-\thesection}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{A part}
\addchap{First Chapter}
\section{First Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First Explanation}
\lipsum[4-5]

\part{Second part}
\addchap{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[6-7]
\section{Failing bookmark Second Introduction}
\lipsum[9-10]
\section{Failing bookmark Second Explanation}
\lipsum

\part{Working Bookmark Part}
\chapter{Working Bookmark Chapter}
\lipsum[6-7]
\section{Working Bookmark Introduction}
\lipsum[9-10]
\section{Working Bookmark Explanation}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to work, unfortunately my minimal working example was too minimal b/c as soon as you have more than one chapter fore each part this stops to work. I guess that is basically due to `\thechapter` returning 0. I've tried to add an extra counter - but little luck.

Comment: You simply need a \newcounter{whatever}, use \thewhatever in \theHsection and then increment it before every \addchap with \stepcounter{whatever}.

Comment: I just saw that scrbook has some code for the anchors of \addchap. So you could try `\renewcommand\theHsection{\HyperLocalCurrentHref-\thepart-\thechapter-\thesection}`

Comment: Ha! Perfect. That works like I imagined it! Should we update it in your solution? edit: I added it.